# Create new array depending of the number of properties in another object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object and depending of the number of properties in that, I need to create a new array.

```
const data = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    company:'Google'
}
```

So, the new array should be like this:

```
const array = [
    0: {
        id: 3434,
        fileId: name, //from data
        criter: 'John Doe;
        address: '12345'
    }
    1: {
        id: 4233,
        fileId: company, //from data
        criter: 'Google;
        address: '32344'
    }
]
```

I have tried to create array and to use Object.keys and Object.values to get the data, but I'm not achieving this.

```
 const testArray = [{
    criter: Object.values(data).map(key => key),
    fileId: Object.keys(data).map(key => key)',
  }];
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please make a [mcve]

Comment: `Object.entries()` will help

Comment: @mplungjan from two (or more) properties in the object `data` I'm trying to create new array with new objects. (in this case two objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries()` will help here

```js
const data = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  company: 'Google'
}

var resultObj = Object.entries(data).map(function(keyvalue) {
  return {
    id: 4233,
    fileId: keyvalue[0], // key
    criter: keyvalue[1], // value
    address: '32344'
  }
});

console.log(resultObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for ??

```js
const data = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    company:'Google'
}

console.log(Object.entries(data).map(([fileId,criter])=>({fileId,criter})));
```

with dummy address and ID :

```js
const data = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    company:'Google'
}

console.log(Object.entries(data).map(([fileId,criter])=>({fileId,criter,id:'1234',address:'1234'})));
```